# Access a value across all threads in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, ruby-on-rails-4, delayed-job

I have a user model and i am setting a value in a thread

```
Thread.current[:partner_domain] = "example.com"
```

I am able to access this in model, but not in delayed job worker, as it runs in separate thread, i can't save this domain in my database due to some business requirement.

**To be more clear i am using `Thread.current[:partner_domain]` in a dynamically created method, that is being invoked by delayed job worker**

Please help me with this.

Comment: Global state FTW! No, don't do it. Or do it at your own risk, if you know what you are doing.

Comment: @bsvin33t how to deal with such things, can you post an answer?

Comment: I have another question, can't you just use something like redis to persist the value ?

Comment: Does this value change for each job or is it static?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it changes for each job.

Comment: @bsvin33t: global state is fine. _Mutable_ global state, on the other hand....

Answer (score 4):

Multithreading has nothing to do with this. DelayedJob worker runs in a separate **process** and, as such, doesn't share anything with your rails server process. Not threads, not memory, nothing.

The right thing to do would be to bundle all the data the job needs into its arguments. Something like this:

```
 MyClass.delay.do_action(primary_data, options)
```

Where `options` contain your partner domain name and all the other info. Then the job just accesses the info from the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

If the delayed job worker needs this value for processing jobs, I think you could pass the value as a job's argument.